# PyQt5 stubs files

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, mypy

I've just started a PyQt5 project that is currently running in a virtualenv.
PyQt5 was installed using a classic *pip install pyqt5*.

I want to type check my application using mypy.
But when I run it, I get an error telling me that there are no stubs file for PyQt5.

```
myapp/__main__.py:3: error: No library stub file for module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets
```

I've checked the site-package of my virtualenv, and indeed, there aren't any *.pyi* file in it.

Checking the [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html#cmdoption-configure-py-no-stubs), I see that if compiled, stub files can be generated (and could at least exists beginning with PyQt5.6, I'm using 5.10).

Is there a way to obtain those file without the need to manually compile the library ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently.

[PEP 561](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0561/), which specifies how packages should indicate they supply type information, was recently accepted. (Full disclosure, I am the author).

PyQt5 will need to become compliant with the PEP, and then as long as you are using mypy >=0.600, everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with PyQt5. So I decided to put up [PyQt5-stubs](https://github.com/stlehmann/PyQt5-stubs) which contains the stub files for the main PyQt5 modules.

You can install it with pip:

```
$ pip install pyqt5-stubs
```

Another solution for you would be to change to *Qt for Python* (PySide2). They provide proper type annotations.

Comment: From what I see PySide2 does *not* provide  proper type annotations - at least for mypy

Comment: I use Pyside2 for a while now and has no problems so far. Can you specify what is missing?

Comment: `Mypy: The stdout of the command line is:
 charts\__main__.py:7:1: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named 'PySide2.QtCharts'
charts\__main__.py:7:1: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
charts\__main__.py:8:1: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named 'PySide2.QtCore'
charts\__main__.py:11:1: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named 'PySide2.QtGui'
charts\__main__.py:13:1: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named 'PySide2.QtWidgets'`
...

Comment: That is odd. What version are you using?

Comment: `>mypy --version
mypy 0.761
>python
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PySide2; PySide2.__version__
'5.14.0'`